# Photo gallery not showing images when clicked on

Tags: javascript, html

The issue is on [here](http://romaniarelocations.com/services.html). The tabs are working just great, but when I click on the last tab: "Vincents Apartment", the images don't show when clicked on.

It's a thumbnail gallery and it worked before on other pages.

It supposed to be working this way: when you click on an image, it should show and you then can click next to see the next image.

I have this js file: photo-gallery.js - I think the problem is here, with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add this code in services.html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">  
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>   
        </div>    
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that code was missing. Now I am seem as a beggar, but if you have time can you help me fix the photo gallery page, the image is showing when clicked on, but when next button is clicked, no other image is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add some html code in services.html page. That is id="myModal" block code. The code is available in gallery.html page. Copy & paste in services.html page. it will work.

`<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-abelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>

            </div>

          <div class="modal-body">

          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>`

Answer (score -1):

your click handler was not registered since the element was injected later, hence not part of the DOM.

if you are using jquery for example. you would replace your usual img or anchor click handler to something like

```
$('body').on('click', 'your img or anchor selector here', function () {

}
```